# Error code 410 when polling Skyscanner flight live prices

Tags: php, api, curl, skyscanner

I am polling live prices from the Skyscanner API. Although I receive the session_key and although I am immediately polling the results I am getting a 410 (Gone) response header with an empty body. It used to work fine from my localhost environment but not on my live server anymore.

Has anybody experienced this before and can maybe give me a hint what the issue could be?

```
$url_api = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/";
$api_key = "XXX"; // Not shown here
$data = array('apiKey' => $api_key, 'country' => 'DE', 'currency' => 'EUR',
'locale' => 'de-DE', 'originplace' => 'HAM', 'destinationplace' => 'AMS', 'cabinclass' => 'economy', 'outbounddate' => '2017-01-27', 
'inbounddate' => '2017-01-30' , 'locationschema' => 'Iata', 'groupPricing' => true);


$httpdata = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $httpdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$headers = get_headers_from_curl_response($response);

$url = $headers['Location']."?apiKey=".$api_key."&stops=0";

echo $url;
return;
```

Comment: provide some code!

Comment: If it works from one system and not from another system then there has to be a difference. So start examining the actual request you send. You can use a simple network sniffer for that and dump the traffic to a file.

Comment: I've added my code now. The URL I am outputting has an empty body and a 410 (Gone) header. It works just fine on my localhost environment.

Comment: I've just read that the Live Price API access has been suspended until further notice! I guess that's the reason...

https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us/articles/206800359-Which-services-can-I-access-and-what-are-the-rate-limits-